# NSURLConnection return (null) value

Tags: php, ios, sql, nsurlconnection

I'm trying to bring a list of values ​​from a table in SQL using PHP

In this way performed the request:

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&Auth=%@", Auth];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"path.php"]]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];

[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;

NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSString *Respuesta = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

And this is my PHP code

```
    <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","dbname");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM DMARCAS");
        $cadena = "";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
      $cadena .=  $row['U_DMarcaName'] . ", ";

      }
        echo $cadena;

    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

In the browser works correctly but on the device I get (null)

I was running tests and I think the error occurs in this line:

If I change $ row ['U_DMarcaName']. , "",  For any string like  the result is correct.

Thank you.

Comment: What's the error say? What's the HTTP response code?

Comment: Also, I think the HTTP header you want is `Content-Type`, *not* `Current-Type`

Comment: Error : Null returningResponse: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x15597330> { URL: filepath/name.php } { status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Date = "Tue, 12 Nov 2013 23:01:13 GMT";
    Server = nginx;
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    "X-Powered-By" = PleskLin;
}

Comment: You parameter is not properly formatted: `@"&Auth=%@"`  The leading character `&` is a separator. You probably want to remove it. You also don't want `allowLossyConversion` - if you have a parameter value with non-ASCII characters. I suspect you only have ASCII?